# Aligned enumerate in multicol

Tags: enumerate, multicol

I want show each two items of "enumerate" in one row, so use the "multicol" package. but i have two problem with this package.

1. In the below sample there are three matrices that number one have 2 dimension and the third have 3-dimension. so in the output the bullets are not aligned.
2. I want see the first and second bullet in same row but the output arrange them in same column.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 
        $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
        $
        \item 
        $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 2 \\
        2 & 2
        \end{pmatrix}
        $
        \item 
        $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & 3 & 3\\
        3 & 3 & 3\\
        3 & 3 & 3
        \end{pmatrix}
        $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems this would be better handled with a table. Any reason why you cannot use that approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `hlist` package, you can meet your requirement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{hlist}2
\hitem
        $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
        $
\hitem
        $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 2 \\
        2 & 2
        \end{pmatrix}
        $
\hitem
        $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & 3 & 3\\
        3 & 3 & 3\\
        3 & 3 & 3
        \end{pmatrix}
        $
    \end{hlist}
\end{document}
```

Ouput:

[image]